# workitem.Save() storing multiple(duplicate) items into TFS

Tags: c#, api, recursion, tfs

I am using below code to store workitem into TFS, but sometimes when TFS is unavailable/ or some exception, it is storing 4 items with same details into TFS. I am using below code.

```
private static void SaveWorkItemtoTFS(WorkItem wi, ref int retryCount)
        {

            try
            {                
                retryCount++;                
                wi.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (retryCount <= 3)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                    wi.SyncToLatest();
                    SaveWorkItemtoTFS(wi, ref retryCount);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
```

I just want to store unique items only. But it is storing 4 items with same details. Can you please help?

Exception is:
Technical information (for administrator):
  The operation has timed out ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequestAndGetResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest, WebException& webException)
   `--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at`TfsProj.BusinessLogic.SaveWorkItemtoTFS(WorkItem wi, Int32& retryCount)
   `at`TfsProj.BusinessLogic.SaveWorkItemtoTFS(WorkItem wi, Int32& retryCount)
   `at`TfsProj.BusinessLogic.SaveWorkItemtoTFS(WorkItem wi, Int32& retryCount)
   `at`TfsProj.BusinessLogic.SaveWorkItemtoTFS(WorkItem wi, Int32& retryCount)
   `at`TfsProj.BusinessLogic.AddNewCertificationTaskIntoTFS(RequestModel objRequestModel, String requestId, String clientReqId)`

this error only occurred once, unable to repro this as well.

Comment: Is the ID available after sync to latest? Can you tell us which TFS version you use and what exceptions occur exactly?

Comment: Can you share the detailed exception message?

Answer (score 0):

According to the exception, the error occurs when get the response from TFS Server. When you create a workitem via `Save()` method, it will send the request to TFS Server first and then waiting for the response to check if the workitem is being created successfully. So in your question, the condition is that the create workitem request is sent successfully and workitem is created successfully but the code didn't get response from TFS Server which cause exception thrown and tried another three times.